# how to get ID of field based on the Max of another field in same table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table named `ae_types`. It contains three fields that are relevant to my question:

```
aetId               This is Auto Increment and is the Primary Key
aetProposalType     Text field 5 characters long
aetDaysToWait       Byte data type
```

`aetProposalType` and `aetDaysToWait` are in a unique key so that I am guaranteed that there will never be two `aetProposalType`s with the same `aetDaysToWait`.

The result that I am looking for is to get the `aetId` of the field with the largest `aetDaysToWait` for each `aetProposalType`.

Below is the query that I have come up with to accomplish this, but it seems to me like it is possibly unnecessarily complicated and not very beautiful.

```
SELECT ae_types.aetId AS lastEmailId, ae_types.aetProposalType
FROM ae_types INNER JOIN 

(SELECT ae_types.aetProposalType, Max(ae_types.aetDaysToWait) AS MaxOfaetDaysToWait 
FROM ae_types GROUP BY ae_types.aetProposalType)  AS ae_maxDaysToWaitByProposalType 

ON (ae_types.aetDaysToWait = ae_maxDaysToWaitByProposalType.MaxOfaetDaysToWait) 
AND (ae_types.aetProposalType = ae_maxDaysToWaitByProposalType.aetProposalType);
```

What are some alternative solutions and why would they be better?

PS If you have any questions please ask and I will be happy to attempt to provide the answer.

Comment: Since you ask about "alternative solutions"... Whenever you tie yourself into pretzel knots, you have to reassess. What business rule are you trying to implement?  There is rarely a good reason to want to know anything about an autoincrementing id.

Comment: Each record in the `ae_types` table represents an event type. These events are ordered by the `aetDaysToWait` field and grouped by the `aetProposalType` field. I need to find the id of the last event for each type. I then check if the current event (data from another table) is the final event and mark it so if it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the way I'd do it too.

```
select a.aetId, a.aetProposalType, a.aetDaysToWait
    from ae_types a
        inner join (select aetProposalType, max(aetDaysToWait) as MaxDays
                    from ae_types
                    group by aetProposalType) sq
            on a.aetProposalType = sq.aetProposalType
                and a.aetDaysToWait = sq.MaxDays
```